# Queue and Pipe serialization through pickle or dill

Tags: python, serialization, multiprocessing, pickle, dill

Has anyone have any luck serialize multiprocessing.Pipe() or multiprocess.Queue() using pickle.dumps() or dill.dumps() and successfully load it back to its original form.

I am using python 2.7.

For example,

```
import dill
import pickle
import multiprocessing

p = multiprocessing.Pipe()
pickled = dill.dumps(p)
original = dill.loads(pickled)
print original
```

Comment: Not intended as an answer, but I'll note that a `multiprocessing.Manager().Queue()` instance *can* be pickled.

Comment: Thanks, i will give that a try.